# php dynamic css dropdown menu from sql db

Tags: php, css, sql, dynamic, drop-down-menu

hello I have recently started learning php & mySql and I am trying to create a dynamic multilevel dropdown menu module , I have been following some tutorials but I can't seem to get it to work please help.

I have 1 table named: menu

id......parent_id....name

1...........0...........home
2...........0...........about
3...........0...........products
4...........2...........what I do
5...........3...........cans

here is the code that I am using.

```
<?php
require_once "db_con.php";

echo '<ul>';
$main_set = "SELECT * FROM menu WHERE parent_id =0 ORDER BY id ASC"; 
$query = mysqli_query($con, $main_set) or die (mysqli_error()); 

$menuDisplay = '';

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { 
    $pid = $row["pages_id"];
    $name = $row["name"];
    $menuDisplay .= '<li><a href="listed_menu.php?pid=' . $pid . '">' . $name . '</a></li>    ';

}

echo $menuDisplay;

echo '<ul>';

$sub_set = "SELECT * FROM menu WHERE parent_id ={$pid} ORDER BY id ASC"; 
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sub_set) or die (mysqli_error()); 

$menuDisplay = '';

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { 
    $pid = $row["pages_id"];
    $name2 = $row["name"];
    $menuDisplay .= '<li><a href="listed_menu.php?pid=' . $pid . '">' . $name2 . '</a></li>    ';

}

echo $menuDisplay;
echo '</ul>';
echo '</ul>';
mysqli_free_result($query); 
?>
```

now it should come to look like this:

- home
- about

  - what I do
- products

  - cans

but it only shows:

- home
- about
- products

and if I put products and cans under parent_id 2  it does show the sub items but not with any other parent_id

Please help me,I'm about to throw something out the window, thnx :)

Answer (score 0):

Your second query isn't inside a loop, so it only runs with the last value of `$pid` (3). That value ("Products") has no subitems, so you don't see any on the screen. Put your second query inside a loop so that you can use each `$pid`.